# IE8 support for HTML custom character entity code "&#x25B6;" (block right arrow)

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, xhtml

I am using HTML character codes for block right arrow in my buttons.

The code is very simple:

`<a href="#" class="button aqua">Details &#x25B6;</a>`

The block arrow looks like this: ▶

The font is Arial: `font: 11pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`

My encoding is UTF-8: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />` and I am using XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype.

In IE 8, I just see a small border box indicating no character found. The arrow has gone missing. Any idea how to make IE8 recognize this, or select the appropriate font / character set?

As an alternative, what I intended to do was replace the character with `&rqauo;` (right angle quote: », supported by IE8) using jQuery. But, I'm using v1.9, which did away with `$.browser` in favor of `$.support.x`. Any way to detect the font / character set being rendered?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, to maximize the odds of having a special character displayed you should declare a `font-family` list of fonts known to contain it and containing fonts that are available in different systems. See [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

For the character “▶” U+25B6 BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE, the [font support page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b6/fontsupport.htm) at Fileformat.info mentions Arial Unicode MS and Lucida Sans Unicode, plus some fonts that are normally not installed on Windows systems. Arial Unicode MS is shipped with Microsoft Office and some other software, whereas Lucida Sans Unicode is shipped with Windows ever since Windows XP. So you should use e.g.

```
<style>
.triangle { font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif; }
</style>
[...]
<a href="#" class="button aqua">Details <span class=triangle>&#x25B6;</span></a>
```

This should fix the problem with IE. However, for some odd reason, when I test this in IE 6 on (virtual) Windows XP, it fails: the character still shows as a box. I cannot tell why, but character rendering in IE 6 is generally very buggy. If you really want to maximize the odds of having the symbol displayed, use an image.

Comment: This helped me out. I was trying to generate via css pseudo `.el:before {content: "\25b6";}` and was getting the box in ie8. I added your rule: `font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Arial Unicode MS", sans-serif;` and that fixed it. I had previously tried `Arial Unicode MS' by itself and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, can't believe it might have been this simple. Still welcome other alternatives, but this appears to work in IE8.

Set the preferred font to a Unicode version of Arial: `Arial Unicode MS`

`font: 11pt "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`

Comment: Yes, but not all computers will have Arial Unicode MS installed (it's not a public domain font) and then browsers will fall back to Arial, which won't work. Use the Character Map to find out which fonts contain your desired character.

Comment: @MrLister, the Character Map tells only which fonts in your own system contain the desired character.

Comment: Yes, but my theory is that if the character is there in a particular font in your own system, it has a larger chance of being there in the same font on other systems.

Comment: That's the problem, the character IS available in character map for "Arial" on my system in the "Unicode" set. But on IE8, on this same system, it's not available.